# Update database with update module disabled

Tags: database

I have recently inherited a site which needs protecting from the recent security exploits. The site has not been very well maintained but the hosting company can provide me with a database dump from 6th October.

Trouble is, the database dump has the update module disabled. When I try to restore the site and upgrade to the latest core version* I am prevented because updating is disabled.

Is there a way of enabling the update module via the database? I am pretty new to drush and do not yet have it enabled on the server.

*Actually it's an early version of Commerce Kickstart 2.

Comment: The Update module is not able to update Drupal; you need to manually copy the files on the server, and run update.php.

Comment: @MrPaul you should check this post https://www.drupal.org/node/157632

Answer (score 0):

Doh. Update wasn't working for me because I didn't exist on the system. Silly mistake

Comment: Just to clarify. The backup I was restoring from, pre-dates the creation of my account on the site. Therefore not permission to update.